# How to start SQL Server Agent etl job after complete Oracle process

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have Oracle source and SQL Server. Every day at 12.00 AM Oracle data populate for oracle database tables, after that sql server agent jobs run manually by me after Oracle Data Extraction completed. for SQL Server databases, I want to automate this process. when oracle data population completed i need to run sql server agent jobs automatically, how can i do this.

Comment: you'd better to ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: So what is driving the Oracle population? To start a SQL Job you connect to the SQL Server with sufficient privileges and call `sp_start_job`

Answer (score 0):

You write a little program that will monitor the oracle process and when it "sees" that is has completed (probably successfully - you skipped that part) it starts the sql server job. Now - how do you do that? How do you know that the process both completed and successfully? Go figure it out based on what functionality Oracle offers and (perhaps) the characteristics of the output that signify success.

Perhaps you can vastly simplify things and schedule some sort of "do it" job that will look for "good" output. Schedule it for a time that is more than sufficient for the oracle process to complete. Do some checking and if things look good, start the other job.